# "Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'CGRect' conform to 'View'"

Tags: swift, swiftui, cgrect

My Code looks something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'CGRect' conform to 'View'
```

How can I use CGRect with SwiftUI?

Comment: I would work through [Apple's SwiftUI tutorial] (https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/). You are entering a wholly new paradigm from UIKit.

Comment: @matt I tried to draw a rectangle, I didn't understood that well before that CGRect are just some measurements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you wanted this

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
          .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

in SwiftUI we should just place views in `body`, instead of *drawing* something.

Note: there are different variants for view layout on screen, depending on needs, but I'd recommend to avoid position hardcoding (like x:20, y:20), because it will give different result on different devices.